# Searching for a special package to describe strings

Tags: fonts, formatting, diagrams

I am quite new in LaTeX and at the moment I am looking for an opportunity to describe strings (or URLs) like this:

[image: example]

Do you know a package I could use for something like this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use TikZ, but please show us what you have tried so far (MWE).

Comment: I've tried nothing yet, because I didn't know how to start!

Comment: Here is a good starting point: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/all/

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

A solution using Ti*k*Z just for fun:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[anchor=base] {$\overbrace{\texttt{jdbc}}$} node[above=2.5ex] {\textsf{\scriptsize Protocol}};
    \node[anchor=base] (a) at (0.5,0) {\texttt{:}};
    \node[anchor=base] (post) at (1.4,0) {$\overbrace{\texttt{postgres}}$};
    \node[anchor=base] (name) at (1.4,1) {\textsf{\scriptsize Product/Vendor Name}};
    \draw[->] (name)--(post);
    \node[anchor=base] (b) at (2.3,0) {\texttt{:}};
    \draw (4.3,0) node[anchor = base] {$\overbrace{\texttt{//localhost:5432/zoo}}$} node[above=2.5ex] {\textsf{\scriptsize Database Specific Connection Details}};
    \node[rectangle, draw=none] (rect) at (0.5,-1) {\textsf{\scriptsize Colon Separators}};
    \draw[->] (a)--(rect);
    \draw[->] (b) to[in=0,out=-90] (rect);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I said ***just for fun*** because this is **not** the optimal way. If the text is not

```
jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/zoo
```

then you have to change (nearly) all the coordinates in, for example, `at (1.4,0)`.

I'm sorry for not providing you the optimal way. As I rarely use something like this, I am a bit unfamiliar. However, the code provided above is basic Ti*k*Z that doesn't really require much effort to make. So I show you that code.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `tikzmark` do make the different elements of your text different nodes, and to annotate them with an `overlay` `tikzpicture`. That way you do not have to re-adjust dimensions if the text changes. (You will, however, have to add vertical space before and after the line since an overlay picture does not add space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\tikzmarknode{jdbc}{jdbc}\tikzmarknode{c1}{:}\tikzmarknode{postgres}{postgres}%
\tikzmarknode{c2}{:}\tikzmarknode{localhost}{//localhost:5432/zoo}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,overbrace/.style args={#1 with #2}{%
thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=1pt},insert path={
(#1.north west) -- (#1.north east)
node[midway,above=2pt,font=\sffamily,align=center]{#2}}}]
\draw[overbrace=jdbc with Protocol];
\draw[overbrace=localhost with Database Specific\\ Connection Details];
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=1pt}] (postgres.north west) --
(postgres.north east) coordinate[midway,above=2pt] (aux);
\draw[latex-] (aux) -- ++(0,12mm)
node[above,font=\sffamily,align=center]{Database Specific\\ Connection Details};
\draw[-latex] (c1) -- ++ (0,-1cm) node[below,font=\sffamily] (CS) {Colon separators};
\draw[-latex] (c2) to[out=-90,in=0] (CS);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]